# Creating a Turtle and placing it in a patch that isnt Black and that doesnt have another turtle in place

Tags: netlogo, agent

I am trying to create turtles and place them randomly along the patches but I cant place them if the patch color is black. Im honestly stuck and cant even think ... This is what I have.

```
create-mice N-mice
  [
    set shape "mouse side"
    set color 4
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  ]
  
  ask turtles [
    while pcolor = black [
      setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    ]
  ]
```

Its giving my an error saying "WHILE expected this input to be a TRUE/FALSE block, but got a TRUE/FALSE instead"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an internal reason for this (the difference between a boolean and a reporter that returns a boolean, or something like that) and it always tricks me too.

When you are doing `while`, the condition is in []. Note that when you are doing `if`, the condition is not in []! Try this:

```
ask turtles [
    while [pcolor = black] [               ; changed the [ ] on this line
      setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: As was explained to me, with `if`, you have `if pcolor = black [ ... ]` and it's only evaluated one time, the `[]` around the condition in `while [pcolor = black] [ ... ]` is meant to stress that the condition is evaluated over and over and can give a different result each time.  But yeah, it has confused me, too!